# Get a result in the units [km/week]

Tags: wolframalpha, unit-conversion

In Wolfram alpha I can use this formular:

```
((7days/week) *(1000km-691.3km) / (today - end of year))
```

and it will display the result using various units.

But I want it in the units Kilometers per Week. I tried various variations, like this one:

```
((7days/week) *(1000km-691.3km) / (today - end of year)) in (km/week)
```

but it can't parse it.

How do I specify the desired units for the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution.

This one actually makes the result a unit less number.

```
((7days/week) *(1000km-691.3km) / (today - end of year)) / (km/wk)
```

Which is good enough for my current purpose. But I still like to get it with the actual units